# Borel $\sigma$-algebra on the unit simplex?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $d\in\{1,2,\ldots\}$ and define the (positive) unit simplex of $\mathbb{R}^d$ via $\Delta=\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^d: \, x_j\geq 0, \, j=1, \ldots,d, \, \Vert x \Vert_1=1 \}$. When defining measures and probability measures on the unit simplex, it is quite common to talk of Borel subsets of the unit simplex, so I'm trying to make some sense of this.

As a preliminary remark, $\Delta$ is clearly a Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$: since it is the set difference between the measurable sets $\Delta=\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^d: \, x_j\geq 0, \, j=1, \ldots,d, \, \Vert x \Vert_1\leq 1 \}$ and $\Delta=\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^d: \, x_j\geq 0, \, j=1, \ldots,d, \, \Vert x \Vert_1 < 1 \}$. Thus, the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\Delta$, i.e.
$$
\sigma(\Delta):=\{ B \cap \Delta : \, B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d) \},
$$
is contained in $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)$, the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathbb{R}^d$. In this view, saying that $S$ is a Borel subset of $\Delta$, actually meaning that $S \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and $S \subset \Delta$, is equivalent to saying that $S \in \sigma(\Delta)$.

On the other hand, is there a Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $\Delta$? Seen as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$, $\Delta$ has empty interior: there is no open set (in $\mathbb{R}^d$) that is a subset of $\Delta$. So how should one interpret the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $\Delta$? Does it correspond to $\sigma(\Delta)$?

Comment: Yes.  $\Delta$ is, by itself, a metric space.  Take the ordinary definition of "Borel sets" for it.  Begin with open sets relative to $\Delta$.  Note that open sets of $\Delta$ are usually not open sets of $\mathbb R^d$.  Prove that these Borel sets of $\Delta$ are the same as $\sigma(\Delta)$ you defined.

Comment: Ok, so one could for example define the set $\Gamma:=\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^{d-1}: \, x_j\geq 0, j=1, \ldots, d-1, \, \Vert x \Vert_1 \leq 1 \}$ and the continuous bijection $\pi: \Delta \mapsto \Gamma: t \mapsto (t_1, \ldots,t_{d-1})$. All the open sets of $\Delta$ (seen as a metric space per se) should thus correspond to inverse images of the open sets of $\Gamma$ through $\pi$, correct?